# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyStyleToUIElement(Unknown Source)

Tags: java-me, linkedin-api, lwuit

I'm running S60 SDK with eclipse pulsar for j2me.
I am trying to load Linkedn login page.
But not geting if i only load linkedin.com by setting htmlc.setPage() then it shows only linkedin name join now &.. but don't show the email & passsword textboxes and login buttons.

my class code given below:

```
public class Login {
    Form form = new Form();
    String authorizeUrl = "";
    LinkedInUser user;

    public Form Login() {
        try {
            Display.init(this);
            HttpRequestHandler  handler = new HttpRequestHandler();// = new AsyncDocumentRequestHandler();
            HTMLComponent htmlC = new HTMLComponent(handler);
            user = new LinkedInUser(Const.consumerKey, Const.consumerSecret);
            user.fetchNewRequestToken();

            if (user.requestToken != null) {
                authorizeUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
                        + user.requestToken.getToken();
            }
            //htmlC.setPage("http://m.google.com");
            System.out.println(""+htmlC.toString());
            System.out.println(""+authorizeUrl);

            //htmlC.setPage("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=5a7ed20d-3a04-419d-85ea-ba99fc06ddbd");
            htmlC.setPage(authorizeUrl);
            System.out.println(authorizeUrl);
            FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(Component.TOP);
            form.setLayout(flow);
            form.addComponent(htmlC);



            //myMIDlet.platformRequest("http://wap.mdfactory.com");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return form;
    }
}
```

I'm getting following set of errors:

```
Uncaught exception!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyStyleToUIElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyStyle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.checkSelector(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.CSSEngine.applyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent.applyAllCSS(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.ResourceThreadQueue.threadFinished(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.streamReady(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.lwuit.html.ResourceThreadQueue$ResourceThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

epocwind.out files some last lines are

```
   734.005  content size: 96.0000x96.0000
   734.010  content size: 96.0000x96.0000
   734.190  WSOCK: Protocol: [0F6414B8] 1 socket(s) have unread data
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] 23 bytes in socket, 0 bytes unread
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] indicating 23 bytes
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] 5 bytes requested, 23 bytes unread
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] received 5 bytes, 18 bytes left
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] 18 bytes requested, 18 bytes unread
   734.190  WSOCK: Protocol: [0F6414B8] 0 socket(s) have unread data
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] 0 bytes in socket, 0 bytes unread
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] received 18 bytes, 0 bytes left
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] 0 bytes in socket, 0 bytes unread
   734.190  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] end of data, I guess
   734.215  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] Shutdown(00000000)
   734.215  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] SetNotify(00000000)
   734.215  WSOCK: ServProvider: [0F646F18] destroyed
   736.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   741.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   746.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   751.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   756.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   761.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   766.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   771.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   776.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
   781.050  WSOCK: Interface: GetDataTransferred(0)
```

Why this is exactly happening  some buddy please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try opening page with http instead of https.

Comment: It's not working .
if i htmlC.setIgnoreCss(true); It works but page showing as simple white page contents are in blue black, and white color.
and after login give me error that enable cookies i checked the emulator browser settings but still same thing is happening